# In Spring Boot - the application database is not creating

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring Boot application. While I am running the application database table is not creating.

Here is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/aymuws
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1101289217

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

The `User` repository class

```
package com.technostack.aymuws.entities;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="_name",unique=false,nullable=false,length=100)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name="_password",unique=true,nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max=12,min=6)
    private String password;

    @Column(name="_task")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @Column(name="_roles")
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLES",joinColumns= {
            @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL",referencedColumnName="email")
    },inverseJoinColumns= {
            @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_NAME",referencedColumnName="name")
    })
    private List<Roles> roles;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public List<Roles> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Roles> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String email, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

The `Task` repository class

```
package com.technostack.aymuws.entities;

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long task_id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String date;
    @NotEmpty
    private String starttime;
    @NotEmpty
    private String stoptime;
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL",referencedColumnName="email")
    private User user;

    // Constructors, setters & getters
}
```

And the `Role` repository class

```
package com.technostack.aymuws.entities;

@Entity
public class Roles {

    @Id
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

The Service class is the following.

```
package com.technostack.aymuws.service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void createUser(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Roles user_role = new Roles("USER");
        List<Roles> create_role = new ArrayList<>();
        create_role.add(user_role);
        user.setRoles(create_role);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void createAdmin(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Roles user_role = new Roles("ADMIN");
        List<Roles> create_role = new ArrayList<>();
        create_role.add(user_role);
        user.setRoles(create_role);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User findone(String email) {
        return userRepository.findOne(email);
    }
}
```

Here is the console when I run the application.

```
00:33:34.875 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
00:33:34.881 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
00:33:34.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/STS%204%20Project%20Workspace/Spring/AymuwsManagementSystem/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.20.RELEASE)

2019-04-22 00:33:35.898  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] .t.a.i.AymuwsManagementSystemApplication : Starting AymuwsManagementSystemApplication on ADMIN-PC with PID 6448 (started by ADMIN in D:\STS 4 Project Workspace\Spring\AymuwsManagementSystem)
2019-04-22 00:33:35.901  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] .t.a.i.AymuwsManagementSystemApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-22 00:33:36.877  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@143eb1f4: startup date [Mon Apr 22 00:33:36 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-04-22 00:33:41.963  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f40d0ceb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-22 00:33:43.478  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-22 00:33:43.619  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-22 00:33:43.620  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.39
2019-04-22 00:33:43.986  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-22 00:33:43.987  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7119 ms
2019-04-22 00:33:44.552  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-04-22 00:33:44.553  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-04-22 00:33:44.554  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-04-22 00:33:44.554  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-04-22 00:33:44.556  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2019-04-22 00:33:44.557  INFO 6448 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Mon Apr 22 00:33:45 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon Apr 22 00:33:47 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2019-04-22 00:33:48.182  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-22 00:33:48.246  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-04-22 00:33:48.501  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-04-22 00:33:48.504  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-04-22 00:33:48.508  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-04-22 00:33:48.622  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-04-22 00:33:49.004  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-04-22 00:33:49.642  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2019-04-22 00:33:49.664  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2019-04-22 00:33:49.758  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-22 00:33:50.844  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@143eb1f4: startup date [Mon Apr 22 00:33:36 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-04-22 00:33:51.194  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-04-22 00:33:51.198  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-04-22 00:33:51.343  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-04-22 00:33:51.344  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-04-22 00:33:51.518  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-04-22 00:33:51.654  WARN 6448 --- [  restartedMain] .t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2019-04-22 00:33:53.669  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: 0ca7d39a-a92e-4e5b-a0e5-8ac4530d5849

2019-04-22 00:33:53.850  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2019-04-22 00:33:54.145  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@27ef81f6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@66a10a07, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3b89247c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@aa4c06d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@13b8cd35, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@77d4b0f1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@31591127, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1245fcf2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@15098ea6, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5e21e0fd, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7ce8e89c]
2019-04-22 00:33:54.683  WARN 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2019-04-22 00:33:54.981  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-04-22 00:33:55.109  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-22 00:33:55.135  INFO 6448 --- [  restartedMain] .t.a.i.AymuwsManagementSystemApplication : Started AymuwsManagementSystemApplication in 20.199 seconds (JVM running for 21.509)
```

I am configuring all the database information in properties file. However, after executing the application I am not being able to create the database.

Comment: Include your main class and any additional configuration classes. It appears that you have placed your main class in its own package but not told Spring to scan the other packages for the various classes.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this configuration in `application.properties` and see if its working

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aymuws?autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
```